# Nested navigators with intermediate views

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation with react-native to create my app.

For a variety of reasons, I need to create nested navigators where the inner navigator is ensconced in a view. So my structure looks like:

`Drawer
  Screen1
    View
      View
        SwitchNavigator1
          ScreenA
          ScreenB
  Screen2
    View
      View
        SwitchNavigator2
          ScreenC
          ScreenD`

Setting things this way creates a bunch of inconsistencies in routing. My guess is that the SwitchNavigators are not "connected" to Drawer (i.e. Drawer is unaware of nested child navs). Is there a way to establish parent-child relationship between nested navigators even if the descendent nav is not a direct child of the navigator?

Answer (score 0):

I just re-read https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html. I believe I can fix this by adding my own component that has a static router and then threads the navigators.